# Wi-Fi not working on fresh install of Ubuntu

Tags: wireless

So I just installed ubuntu and the Wi-Fi doesn't work. It doesn't show the Wi-Fi icon above. The bluetooth doesn't work too, I tried hotspot and it doesn't work too.
My Wi-Fi is Wi-Fi 802.11b/g/n while my bluetooth is Bluetooth 4.0 LE

Comment: Did you try any of the Ubuntu  Wireless Troubleshooting suggestions, most useful is the device recognition and operation section which allows you to search online for fixes, or us to know your hardware and provide help for you.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Yes, I have. I've been exploring for 4 hours now

Comment: Idk if the problem is my wi-fi chip because I have tried it on chromium os and linux mint and it just doesn't work. The only OS where it works is windows 10.

Comment: I also tried the chinese chromium os like nothing works other than windows 10.